# How to make a Web Browser toolbar?

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar, dev-c++

How do I make a Web Browser toolbar in C++. 
in dev-C++ for I.E with no addon libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use Dev C++ I am assuming you want to make IE Addons? 
If thats the case, this should get you started:
[Creating Add-ons for Internet Explorer: Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854%28VS.85%29.aspx) on msdn.microsoft.com

And you should also take a loot at the [Guidelines for add-on developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/09/09/guidelines-for-add-on-developers.aspx) over at IE Blog.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by no add on libraries? win32 is an external library, as is libX11, etc. Dev-C++ makes me think that you want pure win32. In that case, you want the common controls. I found this after a quick google: http://hyper.sunjapan.com.cn/~hz/win32/commctl2.htm . Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

www.besttoolbars.net provides a platfrom for creating toolbar their solution is quite robust and has Javascript API so that you can write all the functionality using Javascript while the toolbar is created on C++.